# Access alfresco using https (SSL) url

Tags: ssl, alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to change the url for accessing Alfresco share from `http://localhost:8080/share` 
to `https://sitename.companyname.com/share`.
I would prefer to make this changes using Alfresco tomcat server and not involve a proxy.

I did the following changes to change the port number:

1. alfresco-global.properties

   alfresco.context=alfresco
   alfresco.host=sitename.companyname.com
   alfresco.port=8443
   alfresco.protocol=https

   share.context=share
   share.host=sitename.companyname.com
   share.port=8443
   share.protocol=https
2. share-config-custom.xml

Change the endpoint url to
`http://localhost:8443/alfresco/`

Can anyone advise as what changes are needed for the https setting?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing ?

Comment: I followed the steps as @mitpatoloya has mentioned and get the error as commented below. Also, I would like to use my company's purchased SSL certificated for the https site.

Answer (score 3):

Steps for using SSL with alfresco

Settings in server.xml

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Settings in alfresco-global.property

- alfresco.context=alfresco
- alfresco.host=sitename.companyname.com
- alfresco.port=8443 alfresco.protocol=https
- share.context=share
- share.host=sitename.companyname.com
- share.port=8443
- share.protocol=https

Settings in share-config-custom.xml

Modify endpoint url accordingly ex. `https://<domain>:8443/alfresco/`

Comment: Hi @mitpatoliya, thanks for replying. I followed the exact steps as you mentioned. When i try accessing https://sitename.mycompany.com/share it gives the following error      log: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8443   . Also I would like to use my own SSL certificate. how can that be done?

Comment: First try to access sitename.mycompany.com/alfresco are you able to access it using https?

Comment: For using your own ssl you need to generate ssl certificate with your domain "sitename.mycompany.com" and register that certificate with your JVM truststore

Comment: I tried accessing just sitename.mycompany.com/alfresco but i get a connection refused error in the logs.

Comment: I had to changed the redirect port to 443 in server.xml as:           <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />          and this to web.xml     <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

Comment: Now it works with https://sitename.mycompany.com:8443/share. No idea as how to get rid of the port 8443 and make it as default.

Comment: hi @juilee did u find a way to get rid of port 8443 ?

Comment: Perhaps the browser is showing 8443 because that's a non-standard port? If you use 443 instead, it should not show the port number.